# Can a registered domain serve the same S3 bucket even if CNAME alias is incorrect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

For static website hosting, Amazon S3 uses virtual hosting i.e. serving multiple websites from a single web server.
I have 2 buckets setup for 'Static website hosting' without mapping DNS names to CNAME aliases. Also, hypothetically, let us say that both S3 buckets are running (are virtual hosted) on the same webserver - this is unlikely but this assumption is important for my question below.

Now, if I register a domain name (say with same name as Bucket1) but created a CNAME alias pointing at Amazon S3 virtual hosted style URL for Bucket2 accidentally, will I still be viewing the index page of Bucket1 when I type in the domain name in a browser?

I am assuming 'Yes', because Amazon S3 sees only the original host header i.e. for Bucket1 and, the web server (of Bucket2) to which the http request landed can also actually serve what is requested in the host header i.e. Bucket1.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 is huge. Each bucket does not run on one particular web server. For example, S3 is distributed across multiple Availability Zones in a Region.

The important thing to remember for Static Website Hosting is ([Configuring a static website using a custom domain registered with Route 53 - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)):

> These bucket names must exactly match your domain name.

This is because S3 uses the URL to determine which bucket to access. Therefore, your example is more likely to fail than to reach the wrong bucket.

Comment: Thanks John. To your response - 'This is because S3 uses the URL to determine which bucket to access' - this is where I get confused; many posts say that the host header in HTTP request is what matters and once the web server is reached, bucket with same name as host header is retrieved & hence my original question. So do you mean the http host header as well as the URL is matched?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think the bucket name must match the domain name because the same "servers" are used for many (or even all) buckets. The only way it can know which bucket you want to access is if the bucket name matches the DNS Name that it is passed. Unlike traditional "web servers" that might serve one website per IP address, S3 serves many buckets from many servers. Thus, it determines the bucket name based on the domain name.